# How to set different properties on stage programmatically?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to set the height, width and backgroundcolor, etc on stage programmatically in a pure AS project. I'm not really sure about how to do that.

I tried to set the height and width like that but it failed..

```
stage.align = StageAlign.LEFT;
            stage.height = 400; 
            stage.width = 500;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stage inherits whatever size you drag and expand it to when published. It doesn't really make sense to "set" it since you can resize it however you want externally. If it's in an HTML page, just set your HTML element/div width/height and the SWF will inherit whatever size the element/div ends up being. On the other hand, if it's a Flex/AIR app and is used in a standalone non-browser context, that's a little different:

```
[SWF(width='800',height='600',backgroundColor='#000000',frameRate='30')]
```

That's Flex-specific though and cannot be used in a regular Flash project.

If it's regular Flash though, it seems like you're thinking it out in the wrong way. Resize [this page](http://clearmpls.com/temp/fullbrowser/) as an example - the stage resizes to the full browser width/height and the textfield just re-center's itself based on that size.

Comment: What about framerate? If you do all things programmatically does it make any sense to set it?

Comment: you can set most things programatically - this.stage.frameRate = 30 - it's just that setting the stage height/width doesn't really matter since you can resize it and thus it'll not be what you set it at - if you resize the swf in your javascript embed or HTML object tag, your dimensions aren't adhered to anymore anyway.

Comment: I'm only doing stuff in Flash Builder, for now I'm doing pure as-projects and other times I'm doing regular Flex-projects.

Answer (score 0):

In a pure AS project in Flash Builder, the `[SWF(...)]` line from jpea's answer is valid too. The only thing to keep in mind is that setting it at runtime won't work for the width and height of the stage.